# Is it possible to automatically delete a burst of photos from Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

When taking pictures I usually do a set of bursts for each shot so that I can select the best one later one. However once I locate the best shot out of the burst there's usually the annoying task of deleting the rest. Likewise I sometimes want to delete an entire burst rather than going through the photos one by one.

Is it possible to automate this within Lightroom? E.g. automatically delete all photos that were taken within 2 seconds from the selected one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no automatic way of doing this. However there is a method that will make it much easier. If you choose **Photo -> Stacking -> Auto-Stack by Capture Time...** you can create stacks of the groups. This will make selecting the photos in the burst that you don't want much easier.

Learning how to shift/ctrl/cmd select multiple photos at once may also help in this regard, such as selecting the first photo, shift clicking the last photo, then ctrl/cmd clicking the photo that you have chosen to keep to deselect it, then pressing delete.

The much easier way to do this is simply use a Flag for the photos you want to keep (Press P for pick when you determine that's the photo you want), then **Edit -> Select by Flag -> Unflagged**, then delete.

There are numerous ways of flagging and selecting photos in Lightroom, you just have to figure out which way works best for your workflow.